# Getview in the listview update all the items in the listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview where I have some textviews and an editText.What I want is that when the text in the editText is changed it should update the corresponding textview in the listview.But the problem is it is updating all the listItems in the listview. My getview code is like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<LItem> lstItems;
    TextView tvAQuantity , tvBQuantity;
    EditText etQuantity;
    LItem p;
    ViewHolder holder;

    ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LItem> objects) {
        ctx = context;
        lstItems = objects;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lstItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lstItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_style_task
                    , parent, false);


            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvAQuan = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAQuantity);
            holder.tvBQuan=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvBQuantity);
            holder.etQuan=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etTaskQuantity);

            holder.tvMatN= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMaterial )   ;
            holder.tvTksN= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTask )   ;
            view.setTag(holder);

        //  tvAQuantity.setText(p.getAQ());
       //   etQuantity.setTag(position);

        }
        else {
            holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();

            }
        p = getProduct(position);
  if(p!=null)
  {
      if(holder.tvAQuan!=null)
    {


      holder.tvAQuan.setText(p.getAQ());
      holder.tvBQuan.setText(p.getBQ());
      holder.tvMatN.setText(p.getMName());
      holder.tvTksN.setText(p.getTName());
        holder. etQuan.setTag(position);
      holder.etQuan.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
              if (!hasFocus) {
                  p.setAQ( holder.etQuan.getText().toString());
                  notifyDataSetChanged();


              }
          }
      });



    }
  }

    //  CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        //cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
    //  cbBuy.setTag(position);
    //  cbBuy.setChecked(p.selected);
        return view;
    }

    LItem getProduct(int position)
    {
        return ((LItem) getItem(position));
    }

    ArrayList<LItem> getBox() {
        ArrayList<LItem> box = new ArrayList<LItem>();
        for (LItem p : lstItems) {
        //  if (p.selected)
            //  box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            //getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag())= isChecked;
        }
    };


    public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView tvAQuan;
        public TextView tvBQuan;
        public EditText etQuan;
        public TextView tvMatN;
        public TextView tvTksN;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your handling getView method wrong. Here i am going to add an sample code.

**Step 1**

You need a viewHolder class like this. Add your inflated xml widgets here:

```
/********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
         public static class ViewHolder{

             public TextView text;
             public TextView text1;
             public TextView textWide;
             public ImageView image;

         }
```

**Step 2**

In your getView method

```
/****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/


         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                 View vi = convertView;
                 ViewHolder holder;

                 if(convertView==null){

                     /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
                     vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

                     /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

                     holder = new ViewHolder();
                     holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
                     holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                     holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

                    /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                     vi.setTag( holder );
                 }
                 else 
                     holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
     return vi;
    }
```

This is sample ask any doubts

**Edit 1:**

In your case change your getView like this

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_style_task
                    , parent, false);
holder .tvAQuantity=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAQuantity ))  ;
holder .tvMaterial = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMaterial );
holder.tvTask = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTask );
holder . tvBQuantity=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBQuantity ));
holder. etQuantity=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etTaskQuantity);
view.setTag(holder);
    }else{
holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}

          p = getProduct(position);



        holder .tvMaterial.setText(p.getMName() ;
        holder.tvTask.setText(p.getTName() );

          holder.tvBQuantity.setText(p.getBQ());

        holder.tvAQuantity.setText(p.getAQ());
        holder.etQuantity.setTag(position);


        return view;
    }
```

And create one ViewHolder class

```
public static class ViewHolder{

             public TextView tvAQuantity, tvTask;
             public TextView tvMaterial;
             public TextView textWide;
             public EditText etQuantity;


         }
```

**Note :**

I don't think the following line you need.

```
holder.etQuantity.setTag(position);
```

Just comment this line and try.

This is sample ask if any help needed

**Edit 2:**

I found the issue. setOnFocusChangeListener is called whenever the focus change and default first time. So once you enter anything in the editText your all the items automatically updated. So you need to use other methods like TExtChanged Listeneer.

Another one issue is You are getting data from p that means getProduct. and again set values to getProduct. What is the purpose of this ?. I think you need to change your logic here.

Comment: this is a list view optimization but what i want is to assign values and handle individual view events in getview.

Comment: I understand that. The reasons you are getting errors in your getView is wrong. That is assigning view is wrong way. Use holder. Your issue will be solved

Comment: can you show me sample code for my code as you are not assigning values to views and not calling events on view as done in my code.

Comment: I tried you method but it is still modifying every list item even if i change the quantity of only one list item edit text...please see my edited question code with your method.

Comment: Did you check the values of p.getAQ(), getBQ()?

Comment: thats fine both these are getting perfect values but the issue is when the etQuantity edit text looses focus it ti supposed to update AQ in the model and update the respected aq but ever listitems gets updated I donot know why

Comment: You mean this is updating all the values right ?p.setAQ( holder.etQuan.getText().toString());

Comment: can you show me some code or link for sample code where logic is perfect.

Comment: What is the purpose of saving text that is entered in edittext

Answer (score 1):

Where is the EditText defined in your holder , first change the declaration of variable etQuan defined in your view holder to EditText instead of textview.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;



    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_style_task
                , parent, false);


        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tvAQuan = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAQuantity);
        holder.tvBQuan=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvBQuantity);

        holder.tvMatN= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMaterial )   ;
        holder.tvTksN= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTask )   ;
        view.setTag(holder);

    //  tvAQuantity.setText(p.getAQ());
   //   etQuantity.setTag(position);

    }
    else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        }

      // edited here
    EditText etQuan=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etTaskQuantity);
    etQuan.setTag(position);
    etQuan.setOnClickListener(ctx);



    p = getProduct(position);
 if(p!=null)
  {
   if(holder.tvAQuan!=null)
  {


  holder.tvAQuan.setText(p.getAQ());
  holder.tvBQuan.setText(p.getBQ());
  holder.tvMatN.setText(p.getMName());
  holder.tvTksN.setText(p.getTName());
    holder. etQuan.setTag(position);
  holder.etQuan.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if (!hasFocus) {
              p.setAQ( holder.etQuan.getText().toString());
              notifyDataSetChanged();


          }
      }
  });



}
}

//  CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    //cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
//  cbBuy.setTag(position);
//  cbBuy.setChecked(p.selected);
    return view;
}
```

And then on the Activity for which your are using this custom adapter do this.

```
    public class Activityname extends ListActivity implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.yourviewname);
    //rest code of your activity
 }

 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    if (v.getId() == R.id.etTaskQuantity) {

        EditText edttxt = (EditText) v;
        LItem obj = (LItem) ListAdapter.getItem((Integer) edttxt
                .getTag());

      // with edttxt do what need to add




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved need to get the parent layout of the view first like this:

```
LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
```

I have modified the code little as I used button click instead of focus change of edit text.

```
 final int     posi=position;

            holder.btnRefreshQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();

                    holder.tvAQuan = (TextView) rl .findViewById(R.id.tvAQuantity);
                    holder.etQuan=(EditText)rl.findViewById(R.id.etTaskQuantity);
                    p = getProduct(posi);
                    p.setAQ(  holder.etQuan.getText().toString() );
                    String s=  holder.etQuan.getText().toString();
                   // Log.d("etQuanText", holder.etQuan.getText().toString());
                   // Log.d("aq",Integer.toString(posi));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```